# Visualising functions from complex numbers to complex numbers

Tags: big-list, math-software, complex-analysis

I think that complex analysis is hard because graphs of even basic functions are 4 dimensional. Does anyone have any good visual representations of basic complex functions or know of any tools for generating them?

Comment: You can think of a function from C to C as a vector field on C, although I don't know of any software that does this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One way that functions from C to C can be represented is to show the image of a grid.  That is, plot the images of the lines x = constant and y = constant under your function, where z = x + yi.

Another is what Wikipedia calls [domain coloring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_coloring) (see [this article by Hans Lundmark](http://www.mai.liu.se/~halun/complex/domain_coloring-unicode.html) for a more detailed exposition.  The idea here is to color the range of the complex function -- since color space is three-dimensional there are multiple ways to do this -- and then color each point in the domain by the color of the corresponding point in the range.

Comment: New address: http://users.mai.liu.se/hanlu09/complex

Answer (score 5):

For Moebius transformations, check out [this nice YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JX3VmDgiFnY).

Comment: Is that from C to C?

Comment: Yep. See wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Möbius_transformation

Comment: That is one extremely cool video!

Answer (score 3):

Open two browser windows side-by-side and use [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/). Recast your function f(z) as f(x+iy) and plot the [real part](http://bit.ly/bEZgsA) in one window and the [imaginary part](http://bit.ly/bfeLyS) in another. My example links provide plots for z<sup>3</sup>.

Answer (score 2):

Oh yes, there's a way to do this. Here is my exploration into the topic about a month ago using Mathematica. The easiest thing to do is to plot the vector field and let the direction of the arrows represent the phase and let the color represent the magnitude. This is a great way to get all four dimensions on a plane and I think it's very enlightening.

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4244/visualizing-a-complex-vector-field-near-poles

Answer (score 1):

The graphs in the middle of [the MathWorld page on Conformal Mapping](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConformalMapping.html) show examples of the first method in Michael Lugo's answer as well as something somewhat similar to the second method in that answer.