# Can we visualize the fact that a holomorphic function has the same derivative at a point in all directions?

Tags: complex-analysis

A holomorphic function $f$ has the same derivative at a point in all directions, but can we visualize this fact?

I guess probably not, at least if we try to visualize $f$'s real and imaginary components as a function of real and imaginary component of $z$.

Since $f=u+iv$ has real and imaginary parts $u, v$ , and the derivative of each part has real and imaginary parts, if we plot only $u$ as a function of $(x+iy)$ or $(x, y)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then this function doesn't have the same derivative at a point in all directions (for **both the derivatives of $u$ and $v$ usually have real and imaginary parts**, say $a_1+ib_1$, $a_2+ib_2$; their 'combination' $a_1+ib_1+i(a_2+ib_2)$ is the same in all directions but that doesn't imply each of them is.

(from somehow a perspective of linear algebra the combination doesn't, like a quaternion, have four independent component but two, and after the combination, the two independent components of the two derivatives somehow intersect each other, or say swops, and so loses their 'individuality'; it's like mixing two bottles of sands and water and that we can't separate out sands in one bottle after the mixture.)

That means we can't find a tangent plane to a point, which would suggest that sameness of derivatives at the point in all directions, of the surface $u(x,y)$ (and $v(x,y)$).

But by using other coordinate systems or decompose $f$ differently, like plot $f(z)=Ae^{i\theta}$ where $z=ae^{i\phi}$ as $A(a, \phi)$ and $\theta(a, \phi)$, would it be possible to visualize the sameness of derivatives at the point in all directions?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by a function having "the same derivative at a point in all directions"?

Comment: I mean $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}$ is the same by whatever path h approaches 0, $z$ is the point, and the derivative in a direction should perhaps be stated as $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0, arg \ of\  h\  being\  constant\ \ \ \ \ }\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/137290/577710 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/951/577710 Visualising functions from complex numbers to complex numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could visualize how the function distorts a grid laid onto its domain, like this: [image: distorted grid]

The fact that the derivative is the same in every direction corresponds to the fact that in a small neighborhood of some point, the transformation can be described by multiplication with the derivative, and multiplication by a complex number is a dilation-rotation. So if we zoom into the grid, the distortion becomes only a rotation, followed by stretching the grid uniformly in some direction. This preserves the angles within the grid. As you can see above, the rectangular grid is distorted to become curved, but all the angles are still right angles. The whole thing gets a bit weird-looking when the derivative is $0$, because grid lines will be smooshed together at such a point, but other than that, we can talk about the angles and notice that they are preserved. In that case (derivative $\neq0$), they're also called locally conformal transformations. That's just the technical name for angle-preserving maps.

Comment: I'd add to this that such maps are called "conformal transformations" !

Comment: @Anthony: Yes. I was holding off on calling them that because it's only true when the derivative is non-zero. But on the other hand, I had to make a special mention of that case anyway, so... Anyway, I'm going to add that to the answer, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I see. It’s similar to cases in single variable and multivariate real functions, where $df=Adx$ where A is a constant or A a transformation matrix w constant entries. Here $df=z_0dz$ and so it’s transforming dz (a vector) to another vector, and if the derivative is continuous nearby z, the transformation is the same (same dilation and rotation) locally. And the grid can be used to visualize the transformation since all dz can be decomposed to linear combination of basis vectors, and the transformation of the linear combination is the same as the linear combination of transformed basis vectors.

Comment: And it’s similar to a differential of homeomorphism between manifolds where grids are also used to partially visualize the differential (It may not visual all the information of the differential because the manifolds can be curved surfaces or more complicated while complex planes are flat.)   Besides, thinking of differentiable function from  R to R, like $f(x) =x^3-x$, where the transformed ‘grid‘ can overlap itself, there seems to be similar cases in holomorphic functions too (not injective)? (In that case we just need to look at the grid ‘locally’)

Comment: @CharlieChang: Yes to everything! And about the local perspective: that's why I called them locally conformal transformations. If the transformed grid doesn't overlap itself (=$f$ is injective), then they're globally conformal, or just conformal. Such maps are important when trying to classify domains according to their analytic behavior (like, are closed contour integrals zero? Can analytic functions on the domain be bounded and non-constant?)